# It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: jquery, cors, couchdb

I am trying this code:

```
$.ajax(
    {
         xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },

    url: 'http://localhost:5984/tdrepo/_design/tdr/_view/repopoolverified?group_level=1',
   type: "GET",

       success: function(result) {

        var $tr = $('<tr/>');
        $tr.append($('<td>').html(result.itemname));
         $tr.append($('<td>').html(result.Repository));
          $tr.append($('<td>').html(result.AIPcount));

            $('.list-order tr:last').before($tr);
```

But I am getting this error:

> Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>   I enabled CORS :
>   enable_cors = true
>   and 
>   [cors]
>   origins = * but it is not working still

Comment: server has to set that header on OPTIONS preflight requests or full request won't get made

Answer (score 1):

problem solved!
I found that I need to make these changes using vim:
sudo vim /etc/couchdb/local.ini

enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *

I didn't find [cors] so I added it, but I put it at the very end of the file; after [admin]

When I put it just after (enable_cors = true
) it worked.